# ios dynamodb not registering tables properly

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, create-table

I downloaded the user preferences example (for Xcode) from the amazon site. I inserted my keys in the code as requested. Then run the app. It is supposed to create a table called TestUserPrefence. It seems to do this correctly in the app, because the app works fine after creating the table and inserting the data; however, when you go to the AWS console for dynamoDB, the table has not been created. Also, when I quit the app and run it again, the table is gone and I have to re-create it.

So how do I add tables in objective c that stick around and that are visible to the aws console?

Here is the code that is supposed to create the tables (copied from the example).

```
#define TEST_TABLE_NAME              @"TestUserPreference"
#define TEST_TABLE_HASH_KEY          @"userNo"


+(void)createTable
{
DynamoDBCreateTableRequest *createTableRequest = [[DynamoDBCreateTableRequest new] autorelease];

DynamoDBProvisionedThroughput *provisionedThroughput = [[DynamoDBProvisionedThroughput new] autorelease];
provisionedThroughput.readCapacityUnits  = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
provisionedThroughput.writeCapacityUnits = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];

DynamoDBKeySchemaElement *keySchemaElement = [[[DynamoDBKeySchemaElement alloc] initWithAttributeName:TEST_TABLE_HASH_KEY
                                                                                           andKeyType:@"HASH"] autorelease];
DynamoDBAttributeDefinition *attributeDefinition = [[DynamoDBAttributeDefinition new] autorelease];
attributeDefinition.attributeName = TEST_TABLE_HASH_KEY;
attributeDefinition.attributeType = @"N";

createTableRequest.tableName = TEST_TABLE_NAME;
createTableRequest.provisionedThroughput = provisionedThroughput;
[createTableRequest addKeySchema:keySchemaElement];
[createTableRequest addAttributeDefinition:attributeDefinition];

DynamoDBCreateTableResponse *response = [[AmazonClientManager ddb] createTable:createTableRequest];
if(response.error != nil)
{
    [AmazonClientManager wipeCredentialsOnAuthError:response.error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", response.error);
}
}
```

More info: I found out that the table was getting created on a different server (North Virginia for some reason) than the one I was looking at on the console (defaulted to Oregon). Apparently you have to create the table in the console on the server your app is going to use; however, there doesn't seem to be a way to set this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  I'm sorry for the trouble.

It appears with a recent update to this sample we lost the change in default to the us-west-2 (Oregon) region for this sample.  This is controlled by the endpoint set on the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` at creation time.  You can simply modify the code in [AmazonClientManager.m](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/samples/DynamoDB_WIF_UserPreference/UserPreference/AmazonClientManager.m#L78) to add the following:

```
ddb.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints ddbEndpoint:US_WEST_2];
```

This will create/use the table in the us-west-2 region.

Answer (score -1):

I found out the solution:

```
Region useast1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
ddb.setRegion(useast1 );
```